# String.split() not working with "[]"

Tags: java, string

I have a IPv6 string

```
String str = "demo1 26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3:2123  demo2";
String searchString = "26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3:2123";
```

When i use str.split(searchString) code returns

```
["demo1 ", "  demo2"]
```

Which is fine but when i use:

```
String str = "demo1 [26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3]:2123  demo2";
String searchString = "[26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3]:2123";
```

and do str.split(searchString) it reutrns

```
[demo1 [26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3]:2123  demo2]
```

Which is wrong i guess , can some one tell why I am getting this sort of output?

Comment: The String.split method takes a regex, you have to ecape the square brackets `"\[26:.....a3\]"`.

Comment: Actually there have to be two slashes before the brackets `"\\[.."`, because the bracket is not an escapable character. This is why you need to escape the slash with another slash. Then your string will look like `"\[..."` which will translate into an escape for the bracket within the regex.

Comment: And that's why I don't post answers when I don't have a minute to test, you are, of course, absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Since split function takes a regex as parameter, you need to escape those brackets otherwise this `[26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3]` would match a single character only.

```
String searchString = "\\[26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3\\]:2123";
str.split(searchString);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because `split(String str)` take regex pattern string as argument. And that string will be used as regex pattern to match all the delimiter with this pattern.

In your regex pattern you are providing character sets in `[]`.

To make it work your way you will have to use this regex pattern string :
`\[26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3\]:2123`

i.e. in java :
`String searchString = "\\[26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3\\]:2123";`

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are familiar with the string regexs. In java, the regex [abc] means match with a OR b OR c I encourage you to escape your square brackets try:

```
String str = "demo1 [26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3]:2123  demo2";
String searchString = "\\[26:11:d0a2:f020:0:0:0:a3\\]:2123";
```

Comment: as I commented on the original post, you need to escape the slash, otherwise it will not compile with an error saying something like "the only escapable characters are ` " '..."

Comment: @Mackiavelli yes you are right, should be \\

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an escape sequence for some special characters. Use `\\[ ... \\]` in the `searchString` variable.